# How to create (optionally) chainable functions like in Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

A common, and very readable, pattern found in Lodash is "chaining". With chaining, the result of the previous function call is passed in as the first argument of the next.

Such as this example from Lodash docs:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 }
];

// A sequence with chaining.
_(users)
  .head()
  .pick('user')
  .value();
```

`head` and `pick` can both be used outside of a chain as well.

Going through the source, there is nothing obviously special about the actual methods being called in the chain - so it must be linked to either the initial `_` call and/or `value` call.

Head: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.11.0/lodash.js#L6443
Pick: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.11.0/lodash.js#L12598

How does one achieve this pattern with their own methods? And does it have a term?

An example might be:

```
const house = 
    this
        .addFoundation("concrete")
        .addWalls(4)
        .addRoof(true)
        .build();

// Functions being (each can be called by manually as well)

addFoundation(house, materialType) { ... }
addWalls(house, wallCount) { ... }
addRoof(house, includeChimney) { ... }

// And..
build() // The unwrapped method to commit the above
```

Comment: You are looking for [`_.mixin`](https://lodash.com/docs#mixin), which is used to create methods. [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.11.0/lodash.js#L15599) and [there](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.11.0/lodash.js#L14708) the magic happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example on how to do it

```
function foo(arr) {
  if (!(this instanceof foo)) {
    return new foo(arr);
  }

  this.arr = arr;
  return this;
}


foo.prototype.add = function(p) {
  this.arr.push(p);
  return this;
}

foo.prototype.print = function() {
  console.log(this.arr);
  return this;
}

foo([1, 2]).add(3).print();
```

Say you want to do this as well

```
foo.add(3).print();
```

You need to create a method on `foo` (not the prototype)

```
foo.add = function(p) {
  return foo([p]);
}

foo.add(3).print() // [3]
```

Comment: Sorry took me a while to process this one - I like it though - makes sense. And explains why in lodash you need to explicitly call _.chain and "unwrap" it with `.value`

Answer (score 1):

It's called method chaining. Here's two articles on it. The basic gist of it is that you return the current object at the end of the function.

http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/

Comment: Ya, nice article but I think its only half the picture (correct me I'm wrong) - in Lodash you can call both `_.pick(object, 'x')` as well as _.(object).pick('x') where the result of the previous operation is passed in as the first argument of the next. In the article above, covers the chain, but not the optional chain