# How to create shorter equivalent for addEventListener

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to create a short function for `addEvenTListener` like jQuery does. I have seperate functions for select and event listener. But I want to be able to use `$(selector).on` instead of `on(event, elem, callback, capture)`. How can I achieve that?

```
function $ (selector, scope) {
    scope = scope ? scope : document;
    return   scope.querySelector(selector);
};

var on = function (event, elem, callback, capture) {

    if (typeof (elem) === 'function') {
        capture = callback;
        callback = elem;
        elem = window;
    }
    capture = capture ? true : false;
    elem = typeof elem === 'string' ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
    if (!elem) return;
    elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
};
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (if I'm generous). What do you expect to actually gain from the shorter invocation?

Comment: I want to write less code and auto avoid to null element errors on event listeners

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create (optionally) chainable functions like in Lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612429/how-to-create-optionally-chainable-functions-like-in-lodash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery returns an array of elements wrapped in jQuery object that provides useful methods in its prototype. So, simplified, it works similar to the code below. The last line is the way you want to attach event listeners to elements (if I understand correctly).

```js
function $(selector, scope){
  let z = Object.create($.prototype);
  z.e = (scope || document).querySelector(selector);
  return z;
}

$.prototype.on = function(event, callback, capture){
  return this.e.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
}

$("button").on("click", ()=>console.log("Clicked!"));
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery returns a wrapper object which exposes the methods `.on()`, `.attr()`, `.prop()` etc, instead of the actual `HTMLElement` instance. So, one way you can accomplish that is to do the same.

Another, *technically feasible* way is to amend the prototype of the `HTMLElement` class:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.on = function(event, callback, capture) { ... };
```

Note, however, that manipulating prototypes you didn't create yourself is **very much not recommended**. It can easily break predefined behavior, perhaps not now but in future versions of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for informative comment. Helped me to understand how it works behind scene

Answer (score 1):

```
Node.prototype.listen = Node.prototype.addEventListener;
```

creates an alias or new reference.

// example

```
el.listen('click', function(){
   // etc.
})
```